# strtok causing segfault but not when step through code

Tags: c, strtok

I am new to C and I am trying to split a date/time string into separate variables. However, when I step through the code in gdb line by line, it works, however, when I let it run through normally without breakpoints it seg faults and I can't see why.

Below is the code:

```
char * dateTimeString = "2011/04/16 00:00";
char dateVar[11];
char timeVar[6];

if (splitTimeAndDateString(dateVar, timeVar, dateTimeString))
{
    exit(1);
}

printf("Date: %s\tTime: %s\n", dateVar, timeVar);
```

Below is the function

```
int splitTimeAndDateString(char date[11], char time[6], char * dateString)
{
    char *token;
    token = strtok(dateString, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            strcpy(date, token);
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            strcpy(time, token);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Overrun date time string\n");
            return 1;
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Not the cause of your issue, but I'd pass all pointers, like this `int splitTimeAndDateString(char *date, char *time, char *dateString)`

Comment: `char * dateTimeString = "2011/04/16 00:00";` - you don't seem to be understanding why string literals are sometimes called string **constants.** `const char *dateTimeString` is the only appropriate declaration.

Comment: Oh, and this is a dupe (out of the other 10000000 ones.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strtok segfault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100214/strtok-segfault)

Comment: And of [strtok segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957829/strtok-segmentation-fault) too.

Comment: And of [strtok giving Segmentation Fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385697/strtok-giving-segmentation-fault) as well.

Comment: I *strongly* advise learners to read K&R. *Strongly* advise. Strings and pointers are basic C concepts. Very basic.

Comment: And if that's not enough, of [Problem with strtok and segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925405/problem-with-strtok-and-segmentation-fault) too.

Comment: @PP. Please make that "very basic" bold and italics.

Comment: (By the way, the four duplicates are literally the **first four** Google hit for "strtok segfault". I simply don't understand **how come** one does **not** start by googling the concatenation of the error message and the name of the suspicious function. That **always works.** And then you don't have to ask a bad duplicate question on Stack Overflow and loose your hard-earned rep...)

Comment: In fact, I pointed out this in *comments * in one of the answers to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499671/want-to-pass-a-single-char-pointer-from-a-double-pointer/17499878#comment25451523_17499878

Comment: http://codepad.org/mHbtXYtT

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `strtok()` function modifies string that you wants to parse, and replace all delimiters with `\0` nul symbol.

Read: [char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

> str
>    C string to truncate.
>    **Notice that the contents of this string
>   are modified and broken into smaller strings (tokens)**. Alternativelly,
>   a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues
>   scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

In your code:

```
 strtok(dateString, " "); 
           ^
           |  is a constant string literal
```

`dateString`  points to `"2011/04/16 00:00"` a constant string literal, and by using `strtok()` your code trying to write on read-only memory - that is illegal and this caused segmentation fault.

Read this [linked answer for diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104953/c-strtok-split-string-into-tokens-but-keep-old-data-unaltered/17104999#17104999) to understand: how `strtok()` works?

**Edit:**

@:  [`char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) In given code example, `str` is an array, not constant string literal. Its declaration:

```
char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
```

Here `str[]` is an nul terminated array of chars, that initialized with string and its length is equals to size of the assigned string. You can change the content of `str[]` e.g. `str[i] = 'A'` is a valid operation.

Whereas in your code:

```
char * dateTimeString = "2011/04/16 00:00";
```

`dateTimeString` is pointer to string literal that is not modifiable  e.g   `dateTimeString[i] = 'A'` is an illegal operation this time.

Comment: I'm not what you mean, I took the example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/. I use dateString in the strToke on the first call, then on the second call within the while loop I use strtok(NULL, " ")

Comment: @Boardy here `char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";` is array not a const string

Comment: @Boardy yes strtok tries to divide the `dataString` in tokens while it is a constant string literal which is  not modifiable. And there is a difference between `str[]` and `*str`.

Comment: Oh OK, now I understand, I've changed it as per @GrijeshChauhan answer he linked to another question where I copy the contents of dateString into a temp variable and use that, which does seem to work, exception after I return and the printf is executed, I then receive an abort even though the print successfully worked

Comment: I did not know this :-) Thanks. From the man page, we have "This end of the token is automatically replaced by a null-character, and the beginning of the token is returned by the function.....The point where the last token was found is kept internally by the function to be used on the next call (particular library implementations are not required to avoid data races).".

Comment: @Boardy It shouldn't about, I compiled the code with `gcc  -Wall -pedantic` and couldn't find and warning, additionally you code **working** fine on [**Codepade**](http://codepad.org/mHbtXYtT) after the rectification I suggested.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, Yea it is working now, not sure what happened, about 5 mins after I got the abort the server locked up and needed a restart and now its working. It is a bit of an old unreliable so basing it was some odd issue with the server. Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.