# C: STRTOK exception

Tags: c, string, strtok

for some reason i get an exception at the first use of strtok() 
what i am trying to accomplish is a function that simply checks if a substring repeats itself inside a string. but so far i havent gotten strtok to work

```
int CheckDoubleInput(char* input){
char* word = NULL;
char cutBy[] = ",_";

word = strtok(input, cutBy);  <--- **error line**

/* walk through other tokens */
while (word != NULL)
{
    printf(" %s\n", word);
    word = strtok(NULL, cutBy);
}
return 1;
}
```

and the main calling the function:

```
CheckDoubleInput("asdlakm,_asdasd,_sdasd,asdas_sas");
```

[image: screenshot of the error im getting]

Comment: `input`  should point to a modifiable array, don't call your function as `CheckDoubleInput("Hello,_word");`

Comment: Read [strtok causing segfault but not when step through code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551665/strtok-causing-segfault-but-not-when-step-through-code/17551779#17551779)

Comment: ok also tried: 
`char* string = "asdasd,_asdasd";
CheckDoubleInput(string);`
still doesnt work

Comment: Try as `char string[] = "asdlakm,_asdasd,_sdasd,asdas_sas";` Read the answer I linked with your question.

Comment: Flelix You should also learn [`Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both stores in memory?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Comment: ok, so how could i use strtok() on a string im getting as an argument in a function?

Comment: Felix:See do like `char string[] = "asdlakm,_asdasd,_sdasd,asdas_sas"; CheckDoubleInput(string);"` Read the answer I have linked exactly answer your question.

Comment: Grijesh Chauhan, thanks, it works with [], but still...i need it to get char* as an argument. :\

Comment: Fleix You don't need to change function arguments type. The problem **was** you were passing a `constant string literal` that can't be modified. So I linked the another question to learn differences between `char*` and `char[]`

Comment: thanks alot! i will read it now

Comment: You can start the process from the copy inside the function, to change the check of a type that does not break the string.

Comment: Please copy the text from the screenshot into the body of the question. You can use "Ctrl-C" to copy the text from most dialog boxes in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

`CheckDoubleInput()` is ok. Look at this. Hope you will understand

```
int main(){
    char a[100] = "asdlakm,_asdasd,_sdasd,asdas_sas";
    // This will lead to segmentation fault.
    CheckDoubleInput("asdlakm,_asdasd,_sdasd,asdas_sas");
    // This works ok.
    CheckDoubleInput(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No it is confusing *`// This will lead to segmentation fault`* Why ?? I think explain it..

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: because it's a pointer to a constant. strtok() modifies first argument.

Comment: Oh so you means your comment is for second line not for second line ... got it.

Answer (score 1):

The `strtok` function modify its first input (the parsed string), so you can't pass a pointer to a constant string. In your code, you are passing a pointer to a string literal of `char[N]` type (ie. a compilation constant string) and hence trying to modify a constant string literal which is undefined behaviour. You'll have to copy the string in a  temporary buffer before.

```
char* copy = strdup("asdlakm,_asdasd,_sdasd,asdas_sas");
int result = CheckDoubleInput(copy);
free(copy);
```

Here is what the [`man` page for `strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) says:

> **Bugs**
>
> Be cautious when using these functions. If you do use them, note that:
>
> - These functions modify their first argument.
> - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.
> - The identity of the delimiting byte is lost.
> - The `strtok()` function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe. Use `strtok_r()` if this matters to you.

Comment: thank, but i cant initialize `char* copy = strcpy("asdlakm,_asdasd,_sdasd,asdas_sas");` like that, i need it to get the *char sent as argument

Comment: @FelixKreuk Actually it should be [`strdup()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c) updated answer. read again

Answer (score 0):

Either `input` is somehow bad. Try printing it before calling `strtok` OR you're using `strtok` on multiple threads with GCC compiler. Some compilers have a thread safe version called 'strtok_r'. Visual Studio have fixed the original function to be thread safe.

Your modified answer shows that you're passing a string literal which is read only.

Comment: you can see that the value of input is ok in the picture i attached

Comment: It's not OK, passing a string literal is dangerous. pass copy of it as strtok will modify it. The memory where the string literal are stored is read only.