# What is the best way to tokenize a string in C++?

Tags: c++

I was trying using strtok(), but it is giving segmentation faults. Could anyone please tell me where the problem is in the code and is there any better way to tokenize a string other than strtok() ?

```
void tokenize(char *tagToFind, char *record, char *delim)
{
    char *token;
    char *itr;
    char *tag;
    char *tag5;
    int toBreak=0;
    token = strtok(record,delim);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
            itr = token;
            while (*itr != '{')
            {
                    tag = itr;
                    itr++;
                    tag++;
            }
            tag = '\0';
            if ((strcmp(tag, tagToFind) == 0))
                    break;
            else
                    token = strtok(NULL,delim);
    }

    if(strcmp(tag5, "tag5") == 0)
    {
            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\ttag5 is present.";
    }
}

int main()
{
    char *tag = "tag5";
    char *record = "tag1{0}|tag2{0}|tag3{0}|tag4{0}|tag5{tag51{0};tag52{0};tag53{0};tag54{0};tag55{tag551{0}:tag552{0}:tag553{0}:tag554{0}:tag555{0}}}";
    char *delim = "|";
    tokenize(tag, record, delim);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Comment: Is this C or C++? If it's the latter, then you should check out std::string

Comment: Segmentation fault is because you are modifying string literal pointed by `record`. `strtok()` modifies first argument read [strtok causing segfault but not when step through code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551665/strtok-causing-segfault-but-not-when-step-through-code/17551779#17551779)

Comment: @crashmstr It is more  C code indeed. edit: opps title says c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char const* const tag = "tag5";
char const* const record = "tag1{0}|tag2{0}|tag3{0}|tag4{0}|tag5{tag51{0};tag52{0};tag53{0};tag54{0};tag55{tag551{0}:tag552{0}:tag553{0}:tag554{0}:tag555{0}}}";
char const delim = '|';

std::stringstream ss(record);
for (std::string token; std::getline(ss, token, delim); ) {
    // Handle token here.
}
```

[Example here](http://ideone.com/Yc8HX1).

Comment: @Mariners should click on right if accepts this answer, and *don't* forgot reading @ [JohnBode's  answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21578521/1673391).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a segfault because you're using `strtok` on a *string literal*.  Remember that `strtok` modifies the input string (it replaces all instances of the delimiters with 0), and modifying a string literal results in undefined behavior; on some platforms (such as yours, apparently), string literals are stored in a read-only memory segment, hence the error.

Your code shouid work with the following change:

```
char record[] = "tag1{0}|tag2{0}|tag3{0}|tag4{0}|tag5{tag51{0};tag52{0};tag53{0};tag54{0};tag55{tag551{0}:tag552{0}:tag553{0}:tag554{0}:tag555{0}}}";
```

Instead of `record` being a pointer to a string literal, it's now an array of `char` that can be modified by your code.

Having said all that, if you're using C++, Simple's solution is probably a better way to go.